# Error setting multiple db symfony 2.5

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine-orm

i'm trying to set 2 databases to my symfony 2.5 project, but got this error:

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'The service definition "doctrine.dbal.default_connection" does not exist.' \services\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ReplaceAliasByActualDefinitionPass.php on line 48

Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: The service definition "doctrine.dbal.default_connection" does not exist. in services\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder.php on line 867

Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Unable to replace alias "doctrine.dbal.default_connection" with "database_connection"
```

Here is my doctrine definition config.yml

```
doctrine:    
    dbal:
        default_connection:   default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     localhost
                port:     ~
                name:     db1
                user:     root
                password: ~
            log:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     localhost
                port:     ~
                name:     db2
                user:     root
                password: ~
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Your config looks good.  Try clearing your cache.

Comment: Solved: Changed by parameters

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

Answer (score 1):

The error message `Unable to replace alias`when fidling with multiple databases hints to a typo in your configuration.

Double check your configuration using this reference: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html